# How to save data to txt when ios app is closed in background because of low memory?

Tags: ios, memory

I'm developing a running app for iPhone.The app can keep running in background.Sometimes the app is closed in background because of low memory.Even Nike+ app has the question too.

So I need to know how to save data in time when app is closed by ios system.

Answer (score 0):

You should save in the method 'applicationDidEnterBackground:'

You can do this in the class appDelegate or add observer for name  UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification